# jquery code for form submit on enter key and without page refresh

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do something like what happens on facebook.I need to make it for my blog.
The issue with this code given below is that it is not responding to the enter key and hence no further execution. But when i simply use the enter key check code without ajaxForm function it responds.

Code:

```
$('#msg').keypress(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
      //checking for enter key as well as shift+enter
      $(document).ready(function() { 
         $('#form1').ajaxForm(function() {
            //for from id=form1 submitting without refreshing the page
            $('#msg').val(''); //clearing out the textarea with id=msg
           //loading fetchposts.php in id=display with new posts
            $("#displaychat").load("fetchposts.php")
         }); 
      }); 
   }
});​
```

In short what i want is that when enter key is pressed the form gets submitted and new results are displayed without page getting refreshed.

Comment: The `.ready` call is not needed as far as I can tell .. are you having a specific problem?  Any error?  What is `.ajaxForm`?

Comment: Why $(document).ready is in your if - else clause?

Comment: @ExplosionPills ajaxForm is the jQuery Form Plugin. Got it from here [link](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js)

Answer (score 0):

You have an unnecessary document.ready function inside your keypress listener

In my code I have attached keypress listener to the body element. That should do the trick

```
$('body').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        $('#form1').ajaxForm(function() { 
            $('#msg').val(''); 
            $("#displaychat").load("fetchposts.php") 
        });
    }
});​
```

Comment: Still not working.
I tried replacing body with #msg as well. The code won't respond to enter key press.